# problem in forward declaring closesocket function

Tags: c++, winsock, forward-declaration

I have a simple winsock in c++ and I don't want to include the entire windows.h header or other winsock headers in the wrapper header

This is to reduce compile times and be lightweight in the ide and to evade the windows.h before winsock headers problem

for most winsock functions it is strait to use them in the cpp implementation file only and let my wrapper do its job of simplifying things

but I only need closesocket function in my header file in order to use it in the raii handle of sockets

```
using socket_t = uintptr_t;
using SocketHandle = std::unique_ptr<void, ZeroOrMinusHandleDeleter<socket_t, static_cast<socket_t>(-1), false, socket_t, closesocket>>;
```

I could use a proxy function and implement it in the cpp file like this :

```
// in .h file
using socket_t = uintptr_t;
int CloseSocket(socket_t fd);
using SocketHandle = std::unique_ptr<void, ZeroOrMinusHandleDeleter<socket_t, static_cast<socket_t>(-1), false, socket_t, CloseSocket>>;


// in .cpp file

int CloseSocket(socket_t fd) { return closesocket(fd); }
```

but I don't want to add extra function call which only redirects to another call

so I tried to forward declare it like this :

```
extern "C"
{
    using socket_t = uintptr_t;
    __declspec(dllimport) int __stdcall closesocket(socket_t s);
}
```

but I got error : C2375 'closesocket': redefinition; different linkage

I tried eliminating __declspec(dllimport) and it compiled but with this warning :

C4273 'closesocket': inconsistent dll linkage

I see the previous one is the same as the definition in WinSock2.h :

```
WINSOCK_API_LINKAGE
int
WSAAPI
closesocket(
    _In_ SOCKET s
    );
```

but I can't understand why it produces this error

UPDATE :

I tired with clang and got these warnings

when using

```
__declspec(dllimport) int __stdcall closesocket(socket_t s);
```

I got

```
warning : redeclaration of 'closesocket' should not add 'dllimport' attribute [-Wdll-attribute-on-redeclaration]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\um\winsock.h(749): note: previous declaration is here
```

and when using

```
int __stdcall closesocket(socket_t s);
```

I get

```
warning : 'closesocket' redeclared without 'dllimport' attribute: previous 'dllimport' ignored [-Winconsistent-dllimport]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\um\winsock2.h(1668): note: previous declaration is here
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\um\winsock2.h(1665): note: previous attribute is here
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\um\winsock2.h(94): note: expanded from macro 'WINSOCK_API_LINKAGE'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\um\winnt.h(184): note: expanded from macro 'DECLSPEC_IMPORT'
```

so it's amazing that I'm warned not to add or remove dllimport to the function declaration !

from the warnings I found that there are two declarations for closesocket and other socket functions

one is in winsock.h header which causes the first warning :

```
int PASCAL FAR closesocket ( IN SOCKET s);
```

and another in winsock2.h which causes the second warning :

```
#if INCL_WINSOCK_API_PROTOTYPES
WINSOCK_API_LINKAGE
int
WSAAPI
closesocket(
    _In_ SOCKET s
    );
#endif /* INCL_WINSOCK_API_PROTOTYPES */
```

it seems that windows.h includes winsock.h so that when my header is included after windows.h I get the first warning

and the second warning is because I include winsock2.h before windows.h in the implementation file and due to this I get the second warning if I evade the first

in conclusion I have to include my header before windows.h or winsock headers so I came to the issue I was trying to solve (the order of inclusion) !

Comment: Look through the winsock header file and find out what `WINSOCK_API_LINKAGE` and `WSAAPI` means.

Comment: The first expands to : __declspec(dllimport) and the other to : __stdcall

Comment: No, in windows platforms it is defined as unsigned integer ULONG_PTR which is the same as uintptr_t